# Angular Material md-tab simulate a tab click?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

Is it possible to simulate a click on a md-tab element? Let's say I have a button on my website which is not anywhere near my md-tab element but I want to force the md-tab group to switch to a specific md-tab when this button is clicked, how could one achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component:

```
mytab = 1; // Index of tab at start

changeTab() {
    this.mytab = 2; // update tab index
}
```

Template:

```
<md-tab-group [selectedIndex]="mytab">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 3">Content 3</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>

<button (click)="changeTab()">Change Tab</button>
```

**Note:** Index starts with Zero.

Source: [Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview), Pluker: [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5IFoVfNRHUiyCTcWQYJK?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!